# Maximize a integral with integral constraint

Tags: integration, functions, optimization

If $g(x)$, $h(x)$ is known, is it possible to find a $f(x)$ to maximize

$$
\int_a^b f(x) \cdot g(x) \,dx
$$

such that

$$
\int_a^b h(f, x) \,dx
$$

is constant. Is there a general way to solve this type of problem? Or is there any books or video on this type of topic.

For example, I want to find a polar curve $R(\theta)$ while keeping area constant

$$
A = \frac 1 2 \int_0^\pi R(\theta)^2\,d\theta
$$

and to maximize

$$
P = \int_0^\pi R(\theta) \, d\theta
$$

Comment: "Calculus of variations" is the method for solving such problems.

Comment: "Mathematics of Classical and Quantum Physics" by Byron and Fuller has a great chapter on variational calculus. Added bonus: its now a Dover reprint, so its relatively inexpensive on Amazon. Note that the particular problem you're describing is a play on the "isoperimetric problem". In problem 2.3 on their book, Byron and Fuller invite you to prove that the simple closed curve with fixed area and minimum perimeter is a circle.

Comment: wow thank u guys very much! I am going to read these immediatly